# Google Apps Script to scan folder and list URLs of files needs to remove listed URLs for deleted files

Tags: javascript

I have been successfully using the script below to list the URLS of all documents in a Google drive folder.  However, it just became apparent to me that if files are removed from the folder they don't get removed from the sheet that I am pushing this list to.

I am thinking I can add code to clear the entire column prior to pushing the updated list each time but am wondering if there is a cleaner way to accomplish this?  This code runs every 20 minutes to keep the list up to date and I don't want to introduce unnecessary inefficiencies into it.  Any ideas are much welcome.

```
    function list_all_files_inside_one_folder_without_subfolders(){
      var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1G7_9zDskN5FZs4frgwnYOtLkEI9DJKtF');
      var list = [];
      list.push(['URL']);
      var files = folder.getFiles();
      while (files.hasNext()){
        file = files.next();
        var row = []
        row.push(file.getUrl())
        list.push(row);
      }
       sh.getRange(2,1,list.length,list[0].length).setValues(list);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function list_all_files_inside_one_folder_without_subfolders() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1G7_9zDskN5FZs4frgwnYOtLkEI9DJKtF');
  var list = [];
  list.push(['URL']);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    file = files.next();
    var row = []
    row.push(file.getUrl())
    list.push(row);
  }
  sh.getRange("A2:A").clearContent(); // <--- Added
  sh.getRange(2, 1, list.length, list[0].length).setValues(list);
}
```

- By this modification, before `list` is put to column "A", column "A" is cleared.

#### Reference:

- [clearContent() of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearContent())

Comment: Thank you!!!  My initial tests show this working exactly as intended.

Comment: @Ryan T About `Thank you!!! My initial tests show this working exactly as intended.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer